# powershell select-string add breaks / new line

Tags: html, powershell

I'm using the select-string in my powershell script

```
Select-String D:\logs\xyz.log -pattern "error"
```

works fine but it gives me back ALL lines of my logfile which include the keyword "error".
As I'm sending an email later with the detected logs a readable structure would me nice, but the content of the select-string does not include any structure.

Best solution would be to add `<br>` after every detected line, because the mail is in html format and this would solve my problem.
I was looking for any parameters of the select-string method but I didn't find a proper solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this might be at least close to what you want to do:

```
$ErrorLines = 
(Select-String D:\logs\xyz.log -pattern "error" |
Select -Expandproperty Line) -join '<br>'
```

Comment: This works fine, but:

Before using this join, my result was like: path+line including the keyword. ex: "D:\logs\xy.log:Error:User not found."

Now it's only the line content, without the path before.

Any idea why? However, this is not a problem. I can print/insert the path manually as well.

Comment: Got it. Of course I should remove the 'Expandproperty' if I want to get path, linenumber and line.

Answer (score 2):

How about formatting the output into an HTML table like so:

```
Select-String D:\logs\xyz.log -pattern 'error' | Select Line -ExpandProperty line | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```